# How to use OSM2PO for transit routing?

Tags: osm2po, transportation, transit

I'm using OSM2PO (4.6.9) for "classic" routing, I mean highway network and everything works fine.

Now, I want to use it to route in a "transport" network, a bus network for instance. But I want the result to take in account bus_stops, so it will not "stop" between two bus stations.

Using PGSQL, shoud be easy to analyse source and targets coords and corresponding nodes to filter, but how can I do that in a Java custom router ?

Hope you understand my very bad english ;)

Comment: Can you give us more details? I mean, what kind of transport are you thinking of exactly? bus routes only? In OSM such things are tagged as relations. Can you ensure, that the OSM data is complete for your purpose and your region?

Comment: Are you looking to develop modeling tools using osm2po or are you looking to transfer existing routes and schedules and aid someone find their way from origin to destination??